# I want to display image, but can I put?

Tags: image, unity-game-engine, object, hover, tooltip

I want to display the image using tooltip. So when I pointing to the 3dobject, it will display the image that I already created.But I did not know what I need to put in the blank space before the imagecomponent.

[image: this is the code that I want to use]

I want to display an image when I hover into the 3d object. I already done the tooltip but it display the text for 3d objects but right now I want to change the text to image.

[image: this the project that I apply tooltip but this will show the text]

[image: but what I want to do is I want to display this image when I hover to the 3d object]

Comment: Dont just put image of code always type it out. What is that `public __________ imageComponent` ?

Comment: I am a little bit confused about what I want to put in there. the real code is 'public TextMeshProUGUI textComponent;' but I change it to 'public __________ imageComponent' but I don't know what to put in there.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it depends on your needs. You have several options:

- Use 3d plane mesh and pass your texture as a parameter to the mesh material.
- Use a `SpriteRenderer` to draw your image in the 3d space
- Use a world canvas and use `UnityEngine.UI.Image` component inside it.

If you just need a simple picture without additional text, buttons, or visual effects, I think, SpriteRenderer will be the best option. You can find good explanation [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jds6oiQIijg).

Comment: ' public SpriteRenderer imageComponent;' <---- like this?  but I get an error it said 'SpriteRenderer' does not contain a definition for 'image'

Comment: It is because SpriteRenderer operates with sprites. Check this link https://gamedevbeginner.com/how-to-change-a-sprite-from-a-script-in-unity-with-examples/#:~:text=To%20change%20a%20Sprite%20from%20a%20script%20in%20Unity%2C%20create,match%20the%20new%2C%20replacement%20Sprite.

Answer (score 0):

If already not using add the `UnityEngine.UI` namespace and use the `Image` type from it

```csharp
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class TooltipManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Image imageComponent;
}
```

Alternatively if you will only be using the `Image` component from `UnityEngine.UI` nothing else then just use it like this.

```csharp
public class TooltipManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public UnityEngine.UI.Image imageComponent;
}
```

---

Then in your `SetAndShowToolTip` method use the `sprite` field of your `imageComponent`

```csharp
public void SetAndShowToolTip(Sprite Image)
{
    gameObject.SetActive(true);
    imageComponent.sprite = Image;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the easy explanation that I really need. But I have an error in **HideToolTip** @SujoyGhosh
  
    'public void HideToolTip()
    {
        gameObject.SetActive(false);
imageComponent.sprite = imageComponent.Destroy;
    } '

Comment: but in the **HideToolTip**, I just want the image will be hidden/empty when I remove the arrow from the object. Do you think the proper method is **Destroy** for the sprite?

Comment: I don't know what's that `Sprite.Destroy` is, custom made object or Unity's own. If it is a method it should have been like this `Sprite.Destory()`. If you only want the image to be hidden why not just disable it with `imageComponent.enabled = false` or if no other component is attached to the `GameObject` of `imageComponent` you can also disable the `GameObject` itself by `imageComponent.gameObject.SetActive(false)` . Remember to enable it by the same way in your `SetAndShowToolTip(Sprite Image)` method.